# About class template in eclipse, how to create a template for class?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create many similar class that is:

inheritance a base class,
have some common annotations.

In eclipse, I can only create a class has a base class, so I wander if there a "template" mechanism in eclipse that can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create various Java code templates in Eclipse via the

Window->Preferences->Java -> Editor -> Templates

Comment: then how to apply this kind of template?

Answer (score 0):

```
class SampleClass<T> {
  private T sampleData;

  public SampleClass() {
  }

  public void set(T sampleData_) {
    sampleData = sampleData_;
  }
}
```

You probably apply the template like above.